# parse error from ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-pagination

I have written some ajax code using an open source library to do jquery pagination. 
when the page first loads, it properly queries and displays the first 25 records from my database.  But all subsequent requests fail with a parse error.
I can't see anything different between the formatting of data in the first page vs. other pages.

I've tried to use JSON Lint but none of my json passes, even the query for page 1. 
My json data looks like this:

```
"[{\"createddatetime\":\"2013-09-10 17:56:54\",\"description\":\"and the final update\",\"number\":\"72212\",\"updatedname\":\"28112\",\"createdname\":\"conversion script\",\"user\":\"28507\",\"position\":\"1\",\"device_id\":\"2\",\"user_id\":\"2\",\"password\":\"Wh16dteaR\",\"updateddatetime\":\"2013-10-07 15:14:28\"},{\"createddatetime\":\"2013-09-10 17:56:54\",\"description\":\"Bauer\",\"number\":\"72787\",\"createdname\":\"conversion script\",\"user\":\"28509\",\"position\":\"2\",\"device_id\":\"4\",\"user_id\":\"4\",\"password\":\"EHVOzIx1\"},{\"createddatetime\":\"2013-09-10 17:56:54\",\"description\":\" Woosly\",\"number\":\"72822\",\"createdname\":\"conversion script\",\"user\":\"28510\",\"position\":\"3\",\"device_id\":\"5\",\"user_id\":\"5\",\"password\":\"IP8rsdOE\"}]"
```

And then I use the parseJSON method to convert the above string into an object. 
Here's the main routine that makes the ajax call and parses:

```
   $.ajax({
      url: mypath + '?startpos=' + page_index * items_per_page + '&numberofrecordstograb=' + items_per_page + '&viewtype=json',
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(data){                           
             data = $.parseJSON(data); //converting to a javascript object vs. just string...       
             if (data !=null) {   

                for(var i=0;i<data.length;i++){
                        var deviceobj = data[i];                        
                        newcontent = newcontent + "<TR>";
                        newcontent=newcontent + '<TD>';    

                        //add EDIT hyperlink
                        if ($("#editdevicesettings").val() == "true") {              
                            var temp  = $("#editlinkpath").val();
                            newcontent=newcontent +  temp.replace("xxx",deviceobj["device_id"]) + '&nbsp;&nbsp;';
                        } 

                        //add DELETE hyperlink
                        if ($("#deletedevice").val() == "true") {              
                            var temp  = $("#deletelinkpath").val();
                            newcontent=newcontent +  temp.replace("xxx",deviceobj["device_id"]);
                        }                                 
                        newcontent=newcontent + '</TD>';

                        newcontent=newcontent + '<TD>' + deviceobj["number"] +'</TD>';
                        newcontent=newcontent + '<<TD>' + deviceobj["user"] + '</TD>';
                        newcontent=newcontent + '<<TD>' + deviceobj["password"] + '</TD>';
                        if (deviceobj["name"]) {
                              newcontent=newcontent + '<TD>' + deviceobj["name"] + '</TD>';
                        } 
                        else  {
                             newcontent=newcontent + '<TD>&nbsp;</TD>';
                        }
                        newcontent=newcontent + '<TD>' + deviceobj["description"]  + '</TD>';
                        newcontent = newcontent + "</TR>";         
                }// end for 
                // Replace old content with new content
                $('#Searchresult').html(newcontent);                    
            }//end if

      },
      error: function(request, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        console.log(textStatus);

      },
      complete: function(request, textStatus) { //for additional info
        //alert(request.responseText);
        console.log(textStatus);
      }
    });

    // Prevent click eventpropagation
    return false;
}//end pageselectCallback()
```

I'm not sure how to go about troubleshooting this. 
Any suggestions would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to reduce the number of records returned to one per page... to narrow down the offending record. 
now that I know which record it is, i should be able to resolve problem.